# NSTimer and Animation synced

Tags: ios, animation, swift, nstimer, caanimation

I'm doing a countdown timer using NSTimer and a circle Animation like this one: [GitHub](https://github.com/perlmunger/PauseAnimation/blob/master/PauseAnimation/MLViewController.m).

My first question is: What CAMediaTimingFunction is for?

My second and most important question is: I'm getting NSTimer and my animation out of sync. Typically the timer reaches 0 before the animation. What is the best approach on this situation?

Comment: Media timing function controls the rate of change during the animation.  For example, ease in slows down as it progresses. Is your aim with the timer to know when the animation completes?  If so, you get a callback triggered (animationDidStop:) instead.

Comment: No, I'm showing a label with a countdown timer and I'm aiming to do a circle animation that start and finishes at the same time as the timer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to be sure you are in sync is not using core animation, but setting the strokeEnd manually in the timer callbacks. I would suggest using a `CADisplayLink` instead of the NSTimer since it is bound to the refresh rate of the display.
Use its `timestamp` to calculate how much time passed and set the label text and the circle's `strokeEnd` appropiately.